# Backward Value Iteration

Tags: motion, motion-planning

I was reading LaValle's [backward value interation](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node54.html) but, completely failed to understand the example 2.9, which is mentioned in the text, works.

Would someone be able to intuitively explain how backward value iteration works?